# PostgreSQL triggers with LibreOffice Base front-end

Tags: postgresql, triggers, libreoffice-base

I have the following trigger function & trigger in PostgreSQL 12.1:

```
create or replace function constraint_for_present()
returns trigger
as $$
BEGIN
if
    new.present_status = 'viewing'
    and new.name not in (select viewable_item from sourcing)
then raise exception 'a present_status of "viewing" requires that the viewable item is in sourcing';
end if;
return new;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger constraint_for_present
    before insert or update of present_status on viewable_item
    for each row
    execute function constraint_for_present();
```

These work as expected during data entry in the psql and TablePlus clients. However, the function throws an error when accessing the database via LibreOffice Base:

```
pq_driver: [PGRES_FATAL_ERROR]ERROR:  relation "sourcing" does not exist  
LINE 2:   and new.name not in (select viewable_item from sourcing)  
    
QUERY:  SELECT new.present_status = 'viewing'  
    and new.name not in (select viewable_item from sourcing)  
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function viewing.constraint_for_present() line 3 at IF  
(caused by statement 'UPDATE "viewing"."viewable_item" SET "present_status" = 'none' WHERE "name" = 'test4'')
```

In Base I have a simple form set up for the trigger's table, with each foreign-key column set to list box, and the Type of list contents set to Sql (also tried Sql [Native]). The List content of each is (with appropriate table and primary key columns):

```
select name from viewing.cv_present_status order by name
```

(This database is using natural keys for now, for organizational political reasons.) The Bound field is set to 0, which is the displayed and primary key column.

So ... 2 questions:

1. Why is this problem happening only in Base, and how might I fix it (or at least better trouble-shoot it)?
2. Since Bound field appears to take only a single integer, does that in effect mean that you can't use list boxes for tables with multi-column primary keys, at least if there is a single displayed column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the trigger function, you can fully qualify the table

```sql
...
   and new.name not in (select viewable_item from viewing.sourcing)
...
```